# Spring JPA with Hikari not releasing connection

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, hikaricp

I have a spring boot application which has a controller. When I try to hit an API simultaneously (35 parrallel hits) it comes to the controller but there I am using findOne of the crudrepository which checks postgres for some data.
The findOne functions returns in milliseconds but the next API doesn't get hold of postgres connection.

I am using HikariCp as the connection pooler with following settings

```
hikari:
 idleTimeout: 10000
 connectionTimeout: 60000
 maximumPoolSize: 30
 minimumIdle: 2
 poolName: gor-srms
 leakDetectionThreshold: 10000
```

In short at any point of time only 30 API's are working in parallel. Once the API is finished then only next one gets postgres connection.

Why is postgres connection not getting used for other API's since the findOne call only takes about millisecs to complete?

Adding the complete application properties:

```
server:
   port: ${SERVER_PORT:${PORT:8093}}
   contextPath: ${mdm.service.contextPath:/wms-masterdata}

spring:
  application:
    name: ${mdm.service.name:mdm-service}
  jmx:
    enabled: false
  profiles:
    active: local
  cloud:
    config:
      discovery:
        enabled: false
        serviceId: config-server
  jpa:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: validate
  http:
      multipart:
        max-file-size: 20MB
        max-request-size: 20MB

discovery:
  enabled: true

eureka:
  client:
    enabled: ${discovery.enabled:true}
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${discovery.url:${REGISTRY_SERVICE_URL:http://localhost:8761}}/eureka/
  instance:
    metadataMap:
      contextPath: ${server.contextPath}

db:
  driver: org.postgresql.Driver
  url: jdbc:postgresql://${database.ip:localhost}:5432/wms_masterdata
  username: postgres
  password: postgres

hikari:
  idleTimeout: 10000
  connectionTimeout: 60000
  maximumPoolSize: 10
  minimumIdle: 2
  poolName: gor-mdm
  leakDetectionThreshold: 60000

hibernate:
  unit_name: wms_masterdata
  show_sql: false
  generate_ddl: false

entitymanager:
  packagesToScan: com.gor.platform.mdm.service.model

butler:
  url: https://192.168.8.116

management:
  security:
    enabled: false
  health:
    db:
      enabled: false

security:
  basic:
    enabled: false

flyway:
  baseline-on-migrate: true
  enabled: true
  ignore-ignored-migrations: true
```

Comment: Did you try increasing the pool size and give a try. Also have you set the datasource type. Can you share the complete config from application properties.

Comment: The number of parallel API's that I can process always gets equal to max pool size.

Comment: @ArpanAgrawal have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
spring.datasource.TYPE=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=20
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=SpringBootJPAHikariCP
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=2000000
spring.datasource.hikari.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.hikari.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
```

Having this kind of setting help to have efficient connection pooling and allowed to server more traffic.

Comment: What is the difference between spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query and spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query

Comment: Did you miss to have two different names?

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to solve this by setting spring.jpa.open-in-view=false. Be aware that this might lead to LazyInitialization Exception